# Can we use CASE in FROM Clause. SELECT * FROM (Case if 1=1 then TABLE1 else TABLE2 end)

Tags: database, db2, case

Can we use **CASE** in FROM Clause. like *SELECT * FROM (Case if 1=1 then TABLE1 else TABLE2 end)*

Comment: Give us some more background on what you intend to do - a simple answer would be "no" - and 1=1 will always be true but I assume you have something else in mind so be more detailed

Comment: Actually I have two tables and based on some condition I have to select data from either table, So i am thinking of using CASE in From Clause. Is it possible Sir ?

Answer (score 0):

This query is wrong with the syntax, what should show next to `Where` is either a table or a table set.

The correct syntax would be:

```
if (1=1) -------------------------be careful here will always be true
begin
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 
end

else
begin
SELECT * FROM TABLE2
end
```

Comment: No Bro, Not if else I wanna use CASE. So that it can hadled in Query and yes  I just give 1=1 for examle

Answer (score 0):

you can use union may be :

```
select * from 
(
select * from table1 where 1=1 --condition 1
union all
select * from table2 where 1=2 --condition 2

) tmp
```